# System.Data.SQLite SQLiteDataReader outputs invalid cast when using one of its methods

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a discord bot that gets its data from a SQLite Database. I am using the `System.Data.SQLite`-Namespace

My problem is this code part:

```
m_dbConnection.Open();
SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
sqlite_cmd = m_dbConnection.CreateCommand();
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = SQLCommand; //SQLCommand is a command parameter
sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            string temp = "";

            try
            {
                temp = sqlite_datareader.GetString(i).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                try
                {
                    temp = sqlite_datareader.GetInt32(i).ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    break;
                }
            }

            output.Add(temp);
            i++;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

For this example the variable `SQLCommand` is `"SELECT Money FROM Users WHERE UserId = 12345 AND ServerID = 54321"`.

When I execute this command in an SQL Editor, , I get the value "10". So the command works. Now when I pass this command in my method, to get the data, I just got with the editor, I get the error `Specified cast is not valid.` at the code `temp = sqlite_datareader.GetString(i).ToString();`.

The value `i` is 0, to get the very first row that the sql command selected. I don't know why this happens, every other SQLite-Command works and gives me what I want. Why isn't this command working too?

Comment: Do you get `"10"` (string) or `10` (int)? As a test, what does `sqlite_datareader[i].GetType()` return?

Comment: *"The value `i` is 0, to get the very first row"* - you mean *column*. The reader reads one row at a time. The first call to `.Read()` puts it on that row, and `i` is the column index. You shouldn't need that `while (true)` loop. Indeed, that may be the root of the problem.

Comment: In the code I try to get the data twice. First I try to get a string. If it doesn‘t work, and I get an error, i catch it and try to get an integer, also with a try-catch. For testing purpose, I‘ve also tried `var x = ...` which gives me the same cast-error

Comment: The values at column index `i` are only going to be of one type, the type of the `Money` column. Read it as that type. These try/catch blocks are unnecessary. What *is* the type of the `Money` column?

Comment: In a different context, where you don't know the type because the query could be arbitrary, use `sqlite_datareader[i]`. Then you can test the type of the value and react accordingly. These are not exceptional cases so exception handling is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it this way

```
 while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
     {
           var ColName = reader.GetName(i);
           var colValue = reader[i]; 
      }
  }
```

Please note that

```
 while (sqlite_datareader.Read()){..}
```

the purpose of the above statement is to fetch all the rows.

therefore I would like to mention the  problems in your code

1-)   `while(true){...}`

is infinite loop, ofcourse in this scenario it would hit the break and quit but still this is not a good practice

2-)  `int i = 0;`

you have declared and increased it by one inside the while loop. The problem here is that:
say you have 100 rows and 10 columns; this means that i would be increased to 99 
however you have 10 colums, trying to get an invalid column value would give you an error

putting your code in try catch/ nested try catch statements would solve the issue however it's a nasty solution.